# Mathematical notation: end of a proof

Tags: notation

What's the difference between $\blacksquare$ and $\Box$ in the end of a proof? I've seen both and I never got the difference.

Comment: No, I just want to know the difference between the black one and the white one? I mean, if $\blacksquare$ is the same as QED, then it answers.

Comment: There is no difference, as much as there is no difference, for a real number $a\geqslant0$, between $a^{1/2}$ and $\sqrt a$.

Comment: None, it's only a matter of choice. You also  can type `| |` or `Q.E.D.` or `Ε.Ο.Δ.`

Comment: Ok, thanks. In that case, I'm going to close the question, once there is a question about this.

Comment: No difference. They both look equally ugly.